# Getting all Active Directory groups that contain a certain description using powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find all groups in Active Directory that contain the word "Dedicated" in the description...

Currently I have the following code:

```
Get-ADgroup -filter {GroupCategory -eq "Security" -and Description -like "*Dedicated*"} | Select-object Name, description
```

I keep getting the following error:

> This operation returned because the timeout period expired

Can anyone help me with my query to return a list of all these groups with their descriptions?

Answer (score 1):

Substring searches on non-indexed attributes (like `description`) can be quite slow if you have many objects in the directory.

What you can do instead is retrieve *all* groups that have a description, and filter them client-side with `Where-Object`.

Be aware that `Get-ADGroup` doesn't return the `description` value by default, you'll need to specify that with the `-Properties` parameter:

```
Get-ADgroup -filter {GroupCategory -eq "Security" -and Description -like "*"} -Properties Description |Where-Object {$_.Description -like "*dedicated*"} |Select-Object Name,Description
```